# AngularJS 1.7 - HTTP POST

Tags: angularjs, post, xmlhttprequest

Upgrade to angularjs version 1.7 and this code does not compile

```
app.factory('LoginService', function ($http) {
        return {
            login: function (param, callback) {
                $http.post(url, param)
                   .success(callback)
                   .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   });
            }
        };
    });
```

On the controller I make the call to the service LoginService

```
    function LoginController($http, $location, LoginService, blockUI) {
    var vm = this;
    LoginService.usuario(
          {login: vm.username, clave: vm.password},
      function (data, status, headers, config) {                
              vm.resultado = data;
              if (vm.resultado == "True") {
                  window.location = "/Home/Index";
              } else {
                  vm.error = 'Usuario o password incorrecto';
              }
          });
};
```

I want to know how the function is called from the controller because it implemented the http.post service using .then

```
app.factory('LoginService', function ($http) {
        return {
            login: function (data) {
                $http.post(url, data)
                    .then(function (resultado) {
                        debugger;
                        if (resultado.data === "True") {
                            return resultado.data;}
                        else {
                              console.log("NO");}
                         });
                       }};
                      });
```

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in the code you have provided. The refactored `.then` version of the LoginService exposes a function named 'login' however your controller is calling `LoginService.usario`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get familiar with a AngularJS [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and its Promise API.

You `LoginService.login(...)` method should return the Promise from `$http.post(...)`:

```
app.factory('LoginService', function ($http) {
    return {
        login: function (data) {
            return $http.post(url, data)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;  
                });
        });
```

Then, your Controller can access the returned data via the resolved Promise:

```
function LoginController(LoginService) {
var vm = this;
LoginService.login({login: vm.username, clave: vm.password})
    .then(function (result) {
        // handle result here...
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I get an error in the 'then' line of the controller, "Cannot read property then of undefined al loginController", 
I will look for the promises as you recommended me

Comment: I'm guessing you missed the `return` in your LoginService. That error is telling you that the _thing_ you are calling `.then()` on is `undefined` - which is the return value of `LoginService.login()`. Ensure you have: `return $http.post(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution would be this:

```
function LoginController($scope,$window,$q,LoginService) {

$scope.fnBusqueda = function () {
    var promesas = [
      obtenerLogin()
    ];

    $q.all(promesas).then(function (promesasRes) {
        var oArrayResponse = promesasRes;
        if ((oArrayResponse.length > 0)) {
            $scope.respuesta = oArrayResponse[0];
            if ($scope.respuesta == "True") {
                window.location = "/Home/Index";
            } else {
                $cope.error = 'Usuario o password incorrecto';
            }
        }
    });


};

function obtenerLogin() {
    var defered = $q.defer();
    var promise = defered.promise;
    LoginService.login(url_valida_login, '{login:X,clave:X}').then(function (response) {
        defered.resolve(response);
    }).catch(function (data) {
        defered.resolve([]);
    })
    return promise;
}
```

}